# How to autoprint new JPEG files from a folder using Python

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi, jpeg, cups

I'm using a Raspberry Pi3 with python 3.5

For a project I need to autoprint every new JPEG image that will come into my folder on my Raspberry Pi3.

I did a lot of research, but did not come across the final answer yet.
What I do have is a printer connected to the Pi with USB and CUPS (that is working properly)

What I now need is a python script that will check if there is a new folder and then if so, autoprints it.

What I did find is a lot about `FindFirstChangeAutofication`
I tried this script:
(changed the path to watch into the folder that needs watching)

```
import os
import time

path_to_watch = ('/home/pi/jebenter/')
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
    time.sleep (10)
    after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
    removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
    if added: print "Added: ", ", ".join (added)
    if removed: print "Removed: ", ", ".join (removed)
    before = after`
```

It is not ready but not sure how to finish it..
And I need a way to send it to my printer.
Does somebody now how to help?

Comment: I improved the formatting of the code and some parts of the question.

Comment: You should probably make a `subprocess.Popen` which calls `lp` and tell it to print the file(s) to your printer.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment above, you could print the files using `lp` or something similar.

I haven't tested this, but it should run:

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

path_to_watch = ('/home/pi/jebenter/')
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
    time.sleep (10)
    after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
    removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
    if added:
        print "Added: ", ", ".join (added)
        subprocess.Popen(["lp", "-d", printer_name, "--"] + added).communicate()
    if removed: print "Removed: ", ", ".join (removed)
    before = after
```